# Shorted path in a 2 dimensional List in Java

Tags: java

I have below array :

```
0 -1 -1
0 -1 -1
0  5  0
```

Here if value is -1 then we should not use that place while parsing, if it is 0 then we can use it. Now if value is not 0 or -1 that is considered as destination.

```
static int shortestPath(List<List<Integer>> array) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            List<Integer> row = array.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < row.size(); j++) {
                int col = row.get(j);
                if (col == 0) {
                    count++;
                } else if (col != -1 && col != 0) {
                    return count;
                }

            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

This worked fine.

But if I enhance the input it is failing for below input

```
 0  0  0 0
-1  0  0 0
-1  0 -1 0
 0  0  8 0
-1 -1  0 0
```

Here result should be 5.

**Explanation**. (0,0) -> (0,1) -> (1,1) -> (2,1) -> (2,2) -> (2,3) so we have 5 navigation points here.

Comment: Can you explain clearly why the result should be 5?

Comment: @Sweeper Added explanation, please check/

Comment: Why don't you use A* algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the way you compute the shortest path to the destination is not correct. 
Your algorithm is just counting the number of occurences of "0" from top to bottom and left to right until we reach the destination.

To find how to compute the length of the shortest path, I suggest you should have a look at:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

It's quite complex to implement and understand, but one of the easiest way to have the correct shortest path in a 2D matrix. 
You will have to deal with some hard concepts: nodes, graphs, algorithms, ... but there are plenty of resources on the internet to get a better understanding of it.

Here is a sample implentation in Java: 
https://github.com/phishman3579/java-algorithms-implementation/blob/master/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/graph/AStar.java

What you need is to define your grid in terms of a graph, with nodes, neighbours, etc.. and, the algorithm should work.